# Plot feature importance computed by Ranger function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot variable Importance using **ranger** function because I have a big data table and **randomForest** doesn't work in my case of study.

This is my code :

```
library(ranger)
set.seed(42)
model_rf <- ranger(Sales ~ .,data = data[,-1],importance = "impurity")
```

Then I create new data frame **DF** which contains from the code above like this

```
> v<-as.vector(model_rf$variable.importance$Importance)
> w<-(as.vector((row.names(df))))
> DF<-cbind(w,v)
> DF<-as.data.frame(DF)
> DF
                           w                v
1                  DayOfWeek 376393213095.426
2                  Customers 1364058809531.96
3                       Open 634528877741.021
4                      Promo 261749509069.205
5               StateHoliday 5196666310.34041
6              SchoolHoliday  6522969049.3763
7                   DateYear  7035399071.0376
8                  DateMonth 20134820116.2625
9                    DateDay 37631766745.2306
10                  DateWeek 32834962167.9479
11                 StoreType 31568433413.5718
12                Assortment 20257406597.8358
13       CompetitionDistance  111847579772.77
14 CompetitionOpenSinceMonth 46332196019.0118
15  CompetitionOpenSinceYear 45548903472.6485
16                    Promo2                0
17           Promo2SinceWeek 50666744628.7906
18           Promo2SinceYear 40964066303.0407
19           CompetitionOpen 39927447341.0351
20                 PromoOpen  28319356095.063
21            IspromoinSales 2844220121.08598
```

But I need to plot a graph like this according to the result shown above:

[image]

**EDIT**

As @Sam proposed I tried to adapt this code:

```
> ggplot(DF, aes(x=reorder(w,v), y=v,fill=v))+ 
+   geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+ coord_flip()+
+   ylab("Variable Importance")+
+   xlab("")+
+   ggtitle("Information Value Summary")+
+   guides(fill=F)+
+   scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="blue")
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale In addition: There
>   were 42 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
>   >

How can I do this, please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please paste your data frame in a format in which we can read it directly. Something such as https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @Axeman, it's from the  `library(ranger)`

Comment: Something like `ggplot(stack(model_rf$variable.impotance), aes(ind, values)) + geom_col() + coord_flip()`

Comment: @Axeman, No it doesn't work

Comment: @Sam, please look at the edited question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is untested but I think this should give you what you are after:

```
ggplot(
    enframe(
        model_rf$variable.importance,
        name = "variable",
        value = "importance"
    ),
    aes(
        x = reorder(variable, importance),
        y = importance,
        fill = importance
    )
) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    coord_flip() +
    ylab("Variable Importance") +
    xlab("") +
    ggtitle("Information Value Summary") +
    guides(fill = "none") +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "blue")
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. But look at the edited question. In fact, I create new data frame to make thing easier. then I try to adapt your code but it doesn't work!

Comment: How does it not work? What error are you getting. Edit your original answer showing me how you tried adapting the code as well as the error message you received please.

Comment: Show me a `str(DF)` Looks like one of your variables are of type factor.

Comment: `> str(DF)
'data.frame': 21 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ w: Factor w/ 21 levels "Assortment","CompetitionDistance",..: 11 6 13 14 20 19 10 8 7 9 ...
 $ v: Factor w/ 21 levels "0","111847579772.77",..: 12 3 19 6 18 20 21 4 11 10 ...`

Comment: Try making `variables` of class character. And that numeric should a of type `numeric` not of type `Factor`. `DF$v <- as.numeric(DF$v)`

Comment: I did it, but look  `Error in validate_guide(guide) : 
  Unknown guide: 0.1148648648648650.02533783783783780.008445945945945950.03378378378378380.2010135135135140.09121621621621620.04898648648648650.1418918918918920.04391891891891890.02364864864864860.02364864864864860.02871621621621620.01182432432432430.01689189189189190.0270270270270270.158783783783784`

Comment: Try removing the `guides()` from the `ggplot` code and see if that works for now.

Comment: Oh thank you ! finaly it works when i delete `guides`